# Subscript Out Of Range using find

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the

> "Subscript Out of Range"

error on the .find line.

The idea is the user selects a cell based on the input box.  The value of Cell(D) in the row of the selected cell would then be copied and used to find the value in Sheet2 in a given range.

```
Sub AddNewLine()

Dim Hull As Variant
Dim SST As Variant
Dim NRE_RE As Variant
Dim DropDownN As Range
Dim DropDownR As Range
Dim foundcell As Variant
Dim myCell As Range
Dim Task As Range
Dim WBS As Range

Set DropDownN = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C6")
Set DropDownR = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C10:C64")

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set myCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a Hull to add the task to 
the 7300", Type:=8)
Set Task = myCell.EntireRow


Task.Select

NRE_RE = Task.Cells(4).Value
Hull = Task.Cells(3).Value
SST = Task.Cells(6).Value

If NRE_RE = "NRE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    With DropDownN
        .Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    End With
ElseIf NRE_RE = "RE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    With DropDownR
        .Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    End With
End If

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

WBS.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End Sub
```

I'm new to coding and have searched for a way to make it apply to my situation with no luck.  I am also trying to name the result of the search as "WBS" which is what the "WBS.Interior.ColorIndex = 3" is referencing.

I'm also aware that my code might not be the most concise but as I get more understanding that will change.  It's just the process as is easiest in my mind.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Find is going to try and return a range which you would need to set to a variable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel e.g.   Set nValue = .Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace your line:

```
.Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
```

With the proper way of using the `Find` function, which involves the following:

1. Set the Result of `Find` to a `Range` object.

   `Dim FindRng As Range
   Set FindRng = .Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)`
2. Also handle a scenario where `Find` wasn't able to find what you are looking for, in the first case it's `SST`.

   `If FindRng Is Nothing Then`

***Modified Code*** for the first `Find` :

```
Dim FindRng As Range

Set FindRng = .Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    ' when Find is successfull finding SST
Else
    ' if Find faild finding SST

End If
```

**Note**: you should avoid using `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` and `Task.Select`, the only thing it's doing is slowing up your code's run-time.

Comment: Thank you!  In my code, I have two separate ranges based on the value in a different sheet.  I'm just curious if I should make another find function (mimicking your code) for each range?  Or can I make an if-then statement prior to the find function that dictates the range to be used?

Comment: @AGB04 you can use this function only once, place it after the End If

Comment: I have updated my code and it is still saying "Subscript Out of Range."  I have:
    If NRE_RE = "NRE" Then  
    Set FindRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C6")  
    Else  
    Set FindRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C10:C63")  
    End If  
    Set WBS = FindRng.Find(What:=SST, LookIn:=xlValue, 
    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)  
    If Not WBS Is Nothing Then  
    WBS.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
    Else  
    MsgBox SST & "could not be found."  
    Exit Sub  
    End If

Answer (score 0):

It is "**xlValues**" ending with "**s**", not "**Xlvalue**":

- [XlFindLookIn enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfindlookin)
- [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)